# Cucumber Java: How to force JSON plugin generation

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

**Overview:** There are instances where in I want to stop the running cucumber test pack midway -- say for example when `x` number of tests failed.

I can do this just fine but I want the json file (`plugin = {json:...}`) to be generated when the test stops. Is this doable?

**What I've tried so far:**

Debug and see where the reporting / plugin generation happens. It seems to be when this line executes:

```
Cucumber.java: runtime.getEventBus().send.....

    @Override
    protected Statement childrenInvoker(RunNotifier notifier) {
        final Statement features = super.childrenInvoker(notifier);
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                features.evaluate();
                runtime.getEventBus().send(new TestRunFinished(runtime.getEventBus().getTime()));
                runtime.printSummary();
            }
        };
    }
```

I was hoping to access the `runtime` field but it has a `private` modifier. I also tried accessing it via `reflections` but I'm not exactly getting what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quite dirty, but working solution and got what I need. Posting my solution here in case anyone might need.

Create a custom cucumber runner implementation to take the runtime instance.

```
public final class Foo extends Cucumber {
    static Runtime runtime;

    /**
     * Constructor called by JUnit.
     *
     * @param clazz the class with the @RunWith annotation.
     * @throws IOException         if there is a problem
     * @throws InitializationError if there is another problem
     */
    public Foo(Class clazz) throws InitializationError, IOException {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected Runtime createRuntime(ResourceLoader resourceLoader, ClassLoader classLoader, RuntimeOptions runtimeOptions) throws InitializationError, IOException {
        runtime = super.createRuntime(resourceLoader, classLoader, runtimeOptions);
        return runtime;
    }
}
```

Call the same line that generates the file depending on the plugin used:

```
public final class ParentHook {

    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario myScenario) {

    }

    @After
    public void afterScenario() {
        if (your condition to stop the test) {
           //custom handle to stop the test
           myHandler.pleaseStop();
           Foo.runtime.getEventBus().send(new TestRunFinished(Foo.runtime.getEventBus().getTime()));
        }
    }
}
```

This will however require you to run your test via `Foo.class` eg:
`@RunWith(Foo.class)` instead of `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)`

Not so much value here but it fits what I need at the moment. I hope Cucumber provides a way to do this out of the box. If there's a better way, please do post it here so I can accept your answer once verified.

Answer (score 0):

Why not quit?

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinitions {

  private static int failureCount = 0;
  private int threshold = 20;

  @When("^something$")
  public void do_something() {
    // something
  }

  @After
  public void after(Scenario s) {
    if (s.isFailed()) ++failureCount;
  }

  @Before
  public void before() {
    if (failureCount > threshold) {
      if (driver !=null) {
         driver.quit();
         driver = null;
      }
    }
}
```